# Laravel multiple where clause is returning just one row

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi we have following table

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| student_name | student_city | student_stream | student_budget |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| Student A    |            2 |              3 |              8 |
| Student B    |            5 |              8 |              9 |
| Student C    |            7 |              7 |              7 |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

now we are apply filters to get all studens with filter for student_city, student_stream and student_budget, here is our following query in laravel eloquent

```
$getStudents = Student::select('student_name ','student_stream','student_city','student_budget');

if($request->budget != 0) {

      $getStudents->whereBetween('student_budget', [$getData['getBudget'][0], $getData['getBudget'][1]]);

 }

 if($request->city != 0) {

       $getStudents->whereIn('student_city', explode(',', $request->city));

 }

 if($request->stream != 0) {

       $getStudents->where('student_stream', $request->stream);

 }

 $result = $getStudents->get();
```

**problem**

Sometimes the result only returns 1 query while the plain same query returns the right number of rows! can anyone tell what could be the problem

**filter url**

/for-you/city/129,17/stream/8/budget/4-8

- 129,17 is the city id
- 8 is the stream id
- 4 - 8 is the budget

Comment: can u post your plain query?

Comment: @TsaiKoga select `student_name`, `student_budget`, `student_city`, 'student_stream' from `students` where `student_budget` between ? and ? and `student_city` in (?, ?) and `student_stream` = ?

Comment: I think you need to debug the parameters.

Comment: @TsaiKoga can you tell how except toSql()?

Comment: you can use `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `DB::getQueryLog()` to get the query with parameters.